# Gettin the value from a selected option in Selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using multiselect in selectize.js, how do i get the vales from the select options:
html:

```
<div class="selectBox1" multiple="multiple">
        <select id="period">
          <option value="day">Day</option>
          <option value="week">Week</option>
          <option value="month">Month</option>
          <option value="year">Year</option>
        </select>
```

select.js init:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  
  $('#period').selectize({
  sortField: "text",
  placeholder: "Select a Period..",
});
});
```

I tried to get the value by simply using this code:

```
var values = $('#period').val();
console.log(values)
```

but it returns an empty array.
what can i do?

Comment: Your code, as provided, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wf9es3uh/   Can you include exactly which version of selectize/js/bootstrap(?) you are using.  Ideally, [edit] and click `[<>]` to make a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue - include all relevant `<script` and `<link rel="stylesheet"` that you are using.

Comment: `$('#period').val()` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/esp906x4/. Check the console output. If it's not working for you then you have a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was able to get the values. Thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan without adding the button and the click it didnt show the output that is the array is still zero

Comment: What array? I only added the button to show how to get the value outside of the plugin initialisation. The `change` event handler still works regardless.

Comment: what I meant was that in the fiddle I tried to store the $period.val() in a variable let v = $period.val(). but then it didnt show an output but in the click event it works

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://jsfiddle.net/wdj2La0u/

Comment: That code is working. It's logging an array because you've set `multiple` on the select.

Comment: `let $v = $period.val()` - `.val()` will get the value **at the time that code runs** - ie when the value of $v is set.   In your updated fiddle you call `$v = $period.val()` **during the page startup** - ie when the page has just loaded.   No options are selected in the HTML, so ... you get an empty array.   What value were you expected to get back when no options were selected?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `onChange` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#period').selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Select a Period..",
    onChange(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here. This answer also doesn't address the issue in the question, that reading the `val()` from the select 'doesn't work'.